# Looping a String Split through Column

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, string, loops

I have a column full of data in a format I don't like, and need them in another format. Currently they are formatted like this: "190826_095630_3E_1 (ROI 0)" and I need just the "3E" portion. I have written a string split that uses the "_" and I figure I can then just take the column of data that is produced that I want, however I can only get this to work one cell at a time while I click each one. I tried to write a for loop but I am running into trouble, most likely because I used "active.cell". Does anyone have a better way to loop this split through my column? Alternatively if you also know how to just return the third string split (3E) I would really appreciate it.

'No loop: This works for one cell

```
Option Explicit

Sub NameTest()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant


    txt = ActiveCell.Value

    FullName = Split(txt, "_")

    For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)

        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)

    Next i


End Sub


'Attempt at a loop: 
Option Explicit

Sub NameTest()
    Dim txt As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim FullName As Variant
    Dim x As Integer

    For x = 1 To 1000

    txt = ActiveCell.Value

    FullName = Split(txt, "_")

    For i = 0 To UBound(FullName)

        Cells(1, i + 1).Value = FullName(i)

    Next i
    Next x

End Sub
```

I would like to get this to run until the last cell with data in a given column.

Comment: I think Text to Columns would work quite nicely and avoid VBA entirely.

Comment: @BigBen Wow! I didn't even know that existed!! I just did that and it works SO well thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad to help out.

Comment: @BigBen Ok so now that I have it all down to 3E, 3F, 3G etc, how can I filter it so that it is both in ascending numerical and alphabetical order? I need the whole data sheet to now be in order from 3 to 1000 as well as A-Z, so that 3A will come before 3G for example? I tried add filter but I don' know how to apply it to both the number and the letter

Comment: Just to add to what @BigBen said, the `Text to Columns` Wizard on the data tab only lets you use a single character delimiter.  If you need more muscle, something that handles a delimiter with multiple characters then you can use `TextToColumns` in VBA or `Split Column by Delimiter` in Power Query.

Comment: @JoeHeiler I would ask that as a new question.

Comment: Since commnts are temporary, @BigBen or OP can post an answer **OR** mark it as a duplicate to some "Text to Columns" question which addresses the same issue :)

Comment: @JoeHeiler feel free to post an answer or maybe just delete the question, or if you want me to add an answer I can, just let me know.